# How to set Container Background image as Image.file() form XFile source in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-container

I am using this function to get images from the gallery

```
_getFromGallery() async {
    XFile? pickedFileGal = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
      maxWidth: 1800,
      maxHeight: 1800,
    );
    if (pickedFileGal != null) {
      XFile imageFileGal = XFile(pickedFileGal.path);
      setState(() {
        _imageFile = imageFileGal;
      });
    }
  }
late XFile _imageFile;
```

I need to set the image to the container background, the container has a child column. So I need to set it in BoxDecoration, but I have the image in XFile the container BoxDecoration image does not take Image.file(). So how can I achieve that? Please guide me

```
Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: Image.file(_imageFile), //Error 
                      ),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        bottom: 15,
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        children: []))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the image here needs to be a `DecorationImage` which then takes `ImageProvider<Object>`.

Knowing this , the correct way to use this is as follows

```
 Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(image: Image.file('file').image)
            ),),
```

Xfile to file

```
Xfile pickedFile;
   Image.file(File(pickedFile.path))
```

Comment: decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: Image.file(_imageFile).image, 
                         ),
                      ),
I followed the instruction still having this error
"The argument type 'XFile' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'."

Comment: I have updated my answer with xfile to file.@Abubakar